# How many machine instructions can single memory address store?

Tags: c, gdb

I'm new in GDB and currently trying to examine memory. I guess title says everything. Basically I compiled some c code and set break point to main. When I type `x/x $eip` it give me back some machine instruction  `0xd02404c7`.
 On the second try `x/5x $eip`
it gives back
 `0x8048426 <main+9>:    0xd02404c7  0xe8080484  0xfffffebe  0x9066c3c9
0x8048436:  0x90669066`
So i got little confused here. The space between addreses 0x8048426--0x8048436 is equal to 10. So it turns out that four instructions took "10 addresses". My questions are:
 Can Memory address store maximum of 4 machine instructions?
Why does it took "10 addresses" to store 4 machine instructions?
Is there any relationship between how much bits does proccesor have and how many machine insturction can single memory address store?
Sorry if the question sounds silly.

Comment: Difference is not 10, it's `0x10`, i.e. 16. One memory address stores one byte (8 bits). Instructions are variable length on x86.

Comment: Some instructions require less memory than others. consider `mov eax ebx`, `neg eax` and `nop`. All three use different amounts of memory, and the amount also depends on the architecture. You should disassemble your code and print instructions to see it more clearly.

Comment: Thank you very very much. One more question please. Memory addreses are hexidecimal right? So if instead of 0x8048436 if it was 0x8048526 difference would be x100 i.e. 16^2?

Comment: *memory addresses are hexadecimal* is not right. gdb displays it to you as hexadecimal, that's all. Generic representation of hexadecimal numbers is to start with `0x`. When you see that, the number is most probably hexadecimal. And yes, the difference is 0x100, or 256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The space between addreses 0x8048426--0x8048436 is equal to 10. So it turns out that four instructions took "10 addresses"

Not quite, it's equal to 0x10, which is an hexadecimal number, and equal to 16 in decimal.
So those instructions are taking 16 bytes.

> Can Memory address store maximum of 4 machine instructions?

Addresses have a granularity of 1 byte. That is, one address refers to exactly one byte.

Machine instructions can take 1 or more byte. So a single memory address, a single byte, can store a maximum of 1 machine instruction, at least on x86.

> Why does it took "10 addresses" to store 4 machine instructions?

Each of the numbers you see is not an instruction. The 4 numbers you see are called words and are what your CPU usually works with.

> Is there any relationship between how much bits does proccesor have and how many machine insturction can single memory address store?

Not really. A single memory address can store at most one instruction. Because instructions are at lest 1 byte long (for x86).

But "how much bits does proccesor have" can indicate that your processor has access to an extended or different instruction set.

Comment: oh... now i get it. Thank you.